# Round a number based on a ratio in C#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I would like to round a number that is based on ratio of two values.

The ratio will include values that are greater or less than the original value where

```
ratio = newValue / originalvalue
```

When **newValue > originalValue** I can round to the nearest lower factor using:

```
double NearestLowerFactor(float value, double factor)
{
    return Math.Floor(value / factor) * factor;
}
```

For example:

- factor = 2
- ratio = 3
- NearestLowerFactor = 2

When **newValue < originalValue** I wish to round to the nearest reciprocal of the factor.

Therefore, if the factor is 2 I would like to round based on factors of 1/2, that is 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc.

For example:

- originalValue = 8
- newValue = 3
- ratio = 0.375
- NearestLowerFactor = 0.25 or 1 / 4.

How would I round to the closest lower factor in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Math.Pow(factor, Math.Floor(Math.Log(ratio, factor)))
```

Comment: This is excellent.  I would have never have thought of it!  It makes me wonder if there is a formula that would work in both cases, that is, **newValue > originalValue** and **newValue < originalValue**. For instance if the ratio is 36 and the factor is 16 then this returns 16 instead of 32.

Comment: It doesn't work for me when `ratio = 36` and `factor = 16`.  Can you confirm that you get 32 with those values?

Comment: I think I understand.  It is not based on multiples.  Therefore 16 * 16 would be the next highest increment.

Comment: @user1423893 Oh, in that case I misunderstood the question, I though both cases were the same. Did I answer your question, though?

Comment: You didn't misunderstand.  It was my misunderstanding.